# Ubuntu 10.04 Cant Adjust brightness on my lenovo Thinkpad?

Tags: nvidia, brightness, thinkpad

I cant seem to be able to adjust the brightness on my think-pad laptop running Ubuntu 10.04. In the power management applet it shows that the power is set to 100%, but even if i try to lower it the actual screen brightness dosent change.

Any ideas of how I can get around this?

I tried changing the brightness from the terminal but its already set to Max brightness (however the actual screen brightness is no that bright at all).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oh，I've met this problem before.All you need to do is:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

find segment like this:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier    "Default Device"
Driver    "nvidia"
Option    "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

change it like this

```
Section "Device"
Identifier    "Default Device"
Driver    "nvidia"
Option    "NoLogo"    "True"
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

JUST ADD THIS LINE:   `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` !

Then restart,It will work.

Comment: Where do i place this line? I tried putting it at the end of the file, and when I restart the laptop is just crashes on boot up (just freezes on the linux load screen).

Comment: lol!Sorry for that,I forgot to tell you that you should add this line in the `Section "Device"` .I'll edit my answer.Sorry for that

Comment: This helped me as well on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get my brightness keys working on my Lenovo W530 on Ubuntu 12.04 (posting here to help people looking for answer in future)...

These days X automatically configures itself, so you can't just edit the xorg.conf file, you, instead need to add a section to a file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and X will include that section in the configuration that it automatically generates.

So to get the screen brightness keys working with your Nvidia graphics card, create a file in the xorg.conf.d directory, e.g:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf
```

Paste the following into the file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro K1000M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Log out and log back in, or reboot, and your brightness keys should now work!

(I blogged this  [here](http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2012/08/enabling-external-monitor-on-lenovo.html))

Comment: I also have a Lenovo W530 on Xubuntu 13.10 and had this same problem. This answer is the only thing that fixed it.