# 13.04 brightness on ThinkPad t430

Tags: 13.04, brightness, lenovo, thinkpad

Cannot adjust brightness on my Thinkpad T430.

This doesn't work anymore: [Ubuntu 10.04 Cant Adjust brightness on my lenovo Thinkpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83965/ubuntu-10-04-cant-adjust-brightness-on-my-lenovo-thinkpad)

Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: Probably related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1098216 Should be fixed in the latest kernels from raring, you should also try the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found a solution. Add a **acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'** option to **/etc/default/grub**:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

And then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#Ubuntu_13.04

Answer (score 0):

Update your Kernel should fix this:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Bug is fixed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1183856